# Unexpected Token Error with jQuery "{"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an unexpected token error when in my console when I run the page.  Can anyone help point out where this is coming from?  I believe I'm going blind because I can't see it.

```
define('QuoteSetupPageController', 'jquery' {
        this.init = function() {
            $(document).click(function(){
                    $('.header-message-indicator').hide(); 
                });    
        }
});
```

Error is on line 1.

Thank you.

Comment: `'jquery' {`, `Unexpected Token Error with jQuery “{”`, `Error is on line 1.` AND YOU STILL CAN'T SEE IT??? (POSTING IN CAPITAL JUST IN CASE)

Comment: Use your console. As Ejay put so eloquently, the exact details of the error, including location, are given as an error. This should be your very first step in diagnosing any javascript problem -- before you ask, check your console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
 define('QuoteSetupPageController', 'jquery', {
```

You were missing a comma.

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed that issue right up.  

I am now getting an unexpected token error on the second line with the period.  Do you have any idea what may be causing that?

Thank you for your time.